# Gnosis Safe Transaction Promises Fail Resolve

Tags: gnosis-safe

Running into an issue where Gnosis Safe (connected through WalletConnect) transaction promises do not resolve in an app (using ethers.js). I put together a basic example to help with debugging if someone on the team can take a look.

Example: https://k50q6l.sse.codesandbox.io/

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gnosis-safe-transaction-promises-fail-resolve-k50q6l

Happy to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is expected for now. It was a bit complicated to implement because of the multi-sig mechanism, but we're looking to improve it in the future.